# SQL single row to multiple rows separated by comma

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get a list of data from SQL Server including the data separated by comma in new rows.

Note : I have only single column name DATA

I have a value like

```
DATA
new
old,yes,now
ok,for
no
```

My required output is:

```
DATA
new
old
yes
now
ok
for
no
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a split functions , Just see if this works for you

```
        CREATE FUNCTION FNC_SPLIT(@MYSTR VARCHAR(500), @DELIMITER CHAR(1))
        RETURNS @MYTBL  TABLE (idx smallint, value varchar(8000))
        AS 
        BEGIN
         DECLARE @RET VARCHAR(500)
         DECLARE @INDEX INT
         DECLARE @COUNTER smallint

         --Get the first position of delimiter in the main string
         SET @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@MYSTR)
         SET @COUNTER = 0

         --Loop if delimiter exists in the main string
         WHILE @INDEX > 0
         BEGIN
            --extract the result substring before the delimiter found
            SET @RET = SUBSTRING(@MYSTR,1, @INDEX-1 )
            --set mainstring right part after the delimiter found
            SET @MYSTR = SUBSTRING(@MYSTR,@INDEX+1 , LEN(@MYSTR) - @INDEX )
            --increase the counter
            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER  + 1 
            --add the result substring to the table
            INSERT INTO @MYTBL (idx, value)
            VALUES (@COUNTER, @RET)
            --Get the next position of delimiter in the main string
            SET @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@MYSTR)
         END

         --if no delimiter is found then simply add the mainstring to the table
         IF @INDEX = 0 
         BEGIN
            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER  + 1
            INSERT INTO @MYTBL (idx, value)
            VALUES (@COUNTER, @MYSTR)
         END 
         RETURN   
        END

        GO

        declare @table table(dt varchar(100));
        insert into @table values
        ('DATA'),
        ('new'),
        ('old,yes,now'),
        ('ok,for');

        select * from @table

        select value from  @table t cross apply dbo.FNC_SPLIT(t.dt,',')
```